# Missing File application.h in gtkmm-3.0 on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: c++, header-files, gnome, gtkmm

I'm currently trying to compile some code examples from

```
http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/sec-treeview-examples.html.en
```

but from what I can see Ubuntu 11.10 gtkmm-3.0 is missing the file

```
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/application.h
```

and I can't find it anywhere else:

```
apt-file search "gtkmm/application.h"
```

returns nothing.

Even more strange, `Application` is *not referenced anywhere* under `/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm`.

Here's the main function

```
#include "../examplewindow.hpp"
#include <gtkmm/application.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.example");
    ExampleWindow window;
    return app->run(window);
}
```

Have I missed something? Has the API changed recently?

After reading the good answers:

For now, with gtkmm 3.2, I use

```
#include "../examplewindow.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Gtk::Main kit(argc, argv);
    ExampleWindow window;
    Gtk::Main::run(window);
}
```

instead. What do I gain by using the 3.4 Application Interface instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Gtk::Application](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/unstable/classGtk_1_1Application.html) documentation, it only exists on gtkmm 3.4+.

You can check the installed version of the package with:

```
pkg-config --modversion gtkmm-3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

There was some issues wrapping GtkApplication for gtkmm 3.0 and 3.2.  It's now in the 3.3.x development sources, but was recently considered "not ready".  I assume it will be in good shape [when 3.4 is released](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtkmm/tree/NEWS).